# Remove edit or add facility for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

Is it possible to remove all references to 'edit' or 'add' from a particular post type on its post list display screen in admin?

So basically what I need is that for this post type, all roles defined, whatever they are, can only view a list of these posts, and not do anything with them except trash them. So that means removing the 'Add New myposttype' button, as well as the 'Edit | Quick Edit' links beneath each entry of the list posts screen.

In my custom post type these are my capability related settings:

```
        'capability_type' => array('food_item','food_items'),
        'map_meta_cap'    => true,
        'capabilities' => array(
                        'publish_posts' => 'publish_food_items',
                        'edit_posts' => 'edit_food_items',
                        'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_food_items',
                        'delete_posts' => 'delete_food_items',
                        'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_food_items',
                        'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_food_items',
                        'edit_post' => 'edit_food_item',
                        'delete_post' => 'delete_food_item',
                        'read_post' => 'read_food_item'
```

In my plugin init function, I'm adding the following:

```
    global $wp_roles;
    $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'edit_food_item' );
    $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'edit_food_items' );
```

At this point the administrator just cannot see the food items entry in the menu at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For say the 'moomin' post type, when defining the custom post type specify its 'capability_type' as 'moomin'.

This will give you the 'capabilities' edit_moomin' etc which you can then remove from individual roles, e.g.:

```
global $wp_roles;
// remove capability edit_moomin from role editor
$wp_roles->remove_cap( 'editor', 'edit_moomin' );
```

@Simon Forster claims readonly posts IS possible, if so then this should do the job:

```
$wp_roles->add_cap( 'editor', 'read_moomin' );
```

Comment: I would like that all roles would not have the capability to add a post of this CPT, else they have all capabilities. How do I do that?

Comment: By repeating the code for each role, there's a list of roles in the codex, e.g. Subscriber etc There's no 'All' or 'Everyone' role

Comment: When I tried the code for the administrator role, I couldn't access the CPT listing of posts either, and I just need to prevent adding of new posts, not disable viewing altogether.

Comment: That's a symptom of how WordPress roles work unfortunately. There's no 'read only' edit page screen in the admin area, that's what the frontend is for, as such it immediately makes the edit pages listing somewhat unusable. A version with no hyperlinks was never made/added

Comment: @TomJNowell Well that's just not true I'm afraid. I run a number of sites with read only post types in the back end. As I've said numerous times, adding the read capability and removing the edit, delete and publish capabilites from user role provides EXACTLY this functionality.

Comment: Well then, if you're correct then the extra line I added to my answer should do the job

Answer (score 1):

As requested...

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_my_post_types' );

function create_my_post_types() {
    register_post_type(
        'name_of_your_post_type_singular',
        array(
            'public' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'name_of_your_post_type_singular'
            ),
        )
    );
}

add_action('admin_init', 'give_user_read', 10, 0);
function give_user_edit() {
    if(current_user_can('edit_others_posts')) {
        global $wp_roles;
        $wp_roles->add_cap('author','read_name_of_your_post_type_plural' );
        $wp_roles->add_cap('editor','read_name_of_your_post_type_plural' );
                etc. etc.
    }
}
```

I've added the read capability to the user roles. As I have not given anyone edit or delete.. they won't have it. As I've given author and editor read access, they will have it.

In case you're not sure what the capabilities will be, when you add the type as I have above you'll generate the capabilities below

```
'capabilities' => array(
            'publish_posts' => 'publish_name_of_your_post_type_plural',
            'edit_posts' => 'edit_name_of_your_post_type_plural',
            'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_name_of_your_post_type_plural',
            'delete_posts' => 'delete_name_of_your_post_type_plural',
            'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_name_of_your_post_type_plural',
            'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_name_of_your_post_type_plural',
            'edit_post' => 'edit_name_of_your_post_type_singular',
            'delete_post' => 'delete_name_of_your_post_type_singular',
            'read_post' => 'read_name_of_your_post_type_singular'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove it by using some css in your plugin within the admin area

In your functions.php file link to some CSS (reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_script');
function my_admin_script()
{
wp_register_style( 'myPluginStylesheet', plugins_url('stylesheet.css', __FILE__) );
}
```

The CSS:

```
a[href="post-new.php?post_type=events"],
#adminmenu a[href="edit.php?post_type=events"],
#adminmenu a.editinline,
#adminmenu a[title="Edit this item"] {
display:none;
opacity:0;
}
```

In the CSS you'll need to replace the references to 'events' with the name of your custom post type. This will work IE7+ I believe using those selectors.

Comment: Thanks, that will indeed accomplish the job from a 'display' perspective, however I wanted a more robust way of doing it, which would actually make those pages inaccessible rather than just hiding their links. If I don't manage to make then inaccessible, the next best solution would be to just hide them via CSS.